# Does the ring of force shield provide AC against incorporeal beings?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Incorporeal beings ignoring normal armor and shields. But the ring of force shield provides a force effect. Does that work, as force-effects work on incorporeals?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes, it does**

Ring of Force shield states:

> An iron band, this simple ring generates a shield-sized (and
>   shield-shaped) wall of force that stays with the ring and can be
>   wielded by the wearer as if it were a heavy shield (+2 AC).

The Wall of Force Spell has the [force] keyword

Incorporeal Creatures say:

> An incorporeal creature’s attacks pass through (ignore) natural armor,
>   armor, and shields, although deflection bonuses and **force effects**
>   (such as mage armor) work normally against it.

Emphasis mine.

Since the Ring duplicates a spell with the [force] keyword, it is a force effect and thus would work normally against incorporeal creatures.

References:

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-force-shield

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wall-of-force

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Incorporeal-Ex-